# error running aws emr create-cluster from powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr, amazon-emr

The following command fails when run in a PowerShell script:

```
aws emr create-cluster --steps file://./monthly_step.json --ec2-attributes KeyName=ff_test,InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole --release-label emr-4.0.0   --instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m3.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m3.xlarge --auto-terminate
```

The error messages are:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in [0]: "InstanceCount"
Missing required parameter in [0]: "InstanceType"
Missing required parameter in [1]: "InstanceGroupType"
Missing required parameter in [1]: "InstanceType"
Missing required parameter in [2]: "InstanceCount"
Missing required parameter in [2]: "InstanceGroupType"
Missing required parameter in [3]: "InstanceCount"
Missing required parameter in [3]: "InstanceType"
Missing required parameter in [4]: "InstanceGroupType"
Missing required parameter in [4]: "InstanceType"
Missing required parameter in [5]: "InstanceCount"
Missing required parameter in [5]: "InstanceGroupType"
```

This same command executes successfully from a standard Windows cmd prompt.

`aws s3` commands work fine from PowerShell.  What causes this `aws emr` to fail?

Comment: Can you prefix that with the call operator `&`?. Might also need to use the stop parsing operator.....

Comment: @Matt yes, calling it like `& aws emr --% create-cluster` works perfectly.  Write an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks for helping me get past this basic powershell weirdness.

Comment: BTW. I am impressed that you were able to test without me spelling it out for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have access to a similar environment for testing but from the looks of it I think PowerShell is seeing arrays in some of your parameters. Even if I am wrong about the specifics of the problem I think the solution is clear.

When you said that it works fine in cmd that is telling me that we need to tell PowerShell to stop interpreting what you are writing. Therefore I think you need to be using the [stop parsing operator `--%`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx). From TechNet:

> The stop-parsing symbol (--%), introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0,
>       directs Windows PowerShell to refrain from interpreting input as 
>       Windows PowerShell commands or expressions.
>
> When calling an executable program in Windows PowerShell, place the 
>       stop-parsing symbol before the program arguments. This technique is 
>       much easier than using escape characters to prevent misinterpretation.

Call operator might not be required here but wouldn't hurt either. Give this a shot:

```
& aws emr --% create-cluster ....
```